# How to created nested list from a list where particular value of list matches in python

Tags: python-3.x

**here I need to get the nested list of list where the value is '01T - 01W' till next occurrence of the value**

```
actual value=['01T - 01W','01T - 02W', '01T - 03W', '02T - 01W', '02T - 02W', '02T - 03W','01T - 01W', '01T - 02W','01T - 01W', '01T - 02W','01T - 01W', '01T - 02W', '01T - 03W', '02T - 01W', '02T - 02W', '02T - 03W']
my requirement=
[['01T - 01W','01T - 02W', '01T - 03W', '02T - 01W', '02T - 02W', '02T - 03W'],
['01T - 01W', '01T - 02W'], 
['01T - 01W', '01T - 02W'], 
['01T - 01W', '01T - 02W', '01T - 03W', '02T - 01W', '02T - 02W', '02T - 03W']]
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question so that it is easier to work out what you're asking.

Comment: please have look on my required output

Comment: Yes, it is _technically_ possible to infer the meaning of the question, but it would be more human readable (and therefore attract more answers) if you were to add a bit of context. (e.g. I want to do ... I've tried... but it didn't work in this way: ...)

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to iterate through the list and create a sublist each time the value '01T - 01W' is encountered

```
for v in value:
    sublist.append(v)
    if v == '01T - 01W':
        requierement.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
requirement.append(sublist) #to append the last sublist to the result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_nested_packages(duct_ids, desired_value):
    nested_list = []
    sublist = []
    for item in duct_ids:
        if item == desired_value:
            if sublist:
                nested_list.append(sublist)
                sublist = []
        else:
            sublist.append(item)
    if sublist:
        nested_list.append(sublist)
    count=1
    for i in nested_list:
        i.insert(0,desired_value)
        i.insert(0,'Package '+str(count))
        count+=1
    print(nested_list)
    return nested_list
```